# Build Design - Docker vs Fedora's Mock

Tags: docker, docker-compose, builds, dependency-management

**This post is migrated from a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/838qm0/build_desgin_docker_vs_fedoras_mock/).  Parts in bold are to adopt it to SE's format.**

I'm talking with companies to help streamline/combine their build process.  They must do it together and their current processes are scary.  We've convinced them to go with AWS/jenkins/bitbucket/artifactory.

Now one company wants to use [fedora's mock](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/mock/wiki) for their build environment deps **and** build artifact management.  Another wants to use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) for their build environment but **does not** have a build artifact solution yet.

I suggested a combination of docker (for build env deps) and mock (for product related artifacts and deps) to both.  They scoffed at it.  BTW one of the products is a custom rhel .iso.

- What are the pros/cons for mock vs docker in the way the two companies are debating using them?
- What about pros/cons for my proposal.. or if it is even a smart thing to do?
- Any other suggested tools/build flow that may work better?

**Ultimately I am interested in what is the best practice/most adopted method for doing this (build env deps mgmt/product artifact dep mgmt) in the industry that will have continued support and advancements?**

Comment: What soft of software are they actually shipping (desktop? server software? their own SaaS service) and what language(s) is it written in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is going to be far more well-known than Mock. I consistently see Docker used during build in companies that I work for. I think I have seen Mock before, but only because I am a Fedora user.

However, Docker is not a build tool in of itself, so you can still use Mock inside a container. This is a great way to avoid the "snowflake" build server. By using Docker containers, your builds are consistent no matter what build tool you are using. You can standardise on Docker as a platform for builds, and leave developers to choose the best build tool (whether that's Mock or NPM).

The only other suggestion I'd have is to run the builds on a CI server, and Docker makes this really easy.

Here's [one example of a company using Docker for builds](https://amaysim.engineering/the-3-musketeers-how-make-docker-and-compose-enable-us-to-release-many-times-a-day-e92ca816ef17) (as well as tests and deploys).